# theorem environment in Arabtex

Tags: theorems, arabic, arabtex

I have this:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{arabbook}
%%%%%%%%%%% packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{arabtex} 
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}% R ensemble des nombres reels
\usepackage{graphicx}% ajouter des photos
\usepackage{pstricks}% pour dessiner
%%%%%%%%%%%% ab3ad AlsfhA
\textwidth= 15truecm % 
\textheight= 22.27truecm % 
\hoffset= -1.5 cm%truecm %
\voffset= -1.5 cm%truecm %
%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
% `dm Alt^skyl 
\novocalize
% bdAyt Alw_tyqT
\rhead{\RL{Alf.sl Al'awl}}
\lhead{\RL{`nwAn Alf.sl}}
\begin{document}
\begin{arabtext}

\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

I want to define the theorem environment, to obtain "nzryT 1: ..."

How to do it please?

Thank you

Comment: not what you want, but i think it's better to use xelatex here is an [example (not the best but...)](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/st-at-tryf-lldl-at-lsy-at-llss-$e$/rsnjbgzrzsgr#.WklP6tLibcc)

Comment: @touhami i want to write with "latin" to obtain Arabic, not use directly Arabic, because i write the document

Comment: @touhami i can't define it ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: What is `nzryT`? Is that Arabic for `number?` or `Theorem`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Theorem

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Unfortunately I can't neither read nor speak Arabic

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Does  `\newtheorem{theorem}{\begin{arabtex}nzryT\end{arabtex}}` in the preamble help?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer how can call it ? \begin{?} please?

Comment: `\begin{theorem}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it doesn't work

Comment: `arabxetex` allows and even encourages using the ASCII input found in `arabtex`, so that’s not a reason to avoid `xelatex`. @touhami’s suggestion is a good one.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: `doesn't work' is no useful description

Comment: @touhami please i have problems with your answer i can make \chapter, and the numerotation 1,2,... please answer me

Comment: @Vrouvrou answer edited. Please see comments below.

Comment: @touhami sorry, the numbering still the same

Comment: @touhami are you here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with xelatex and the package arabxetex.

```
\documentclass{book}
%---------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
%---------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%---------------------------------------------
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\makeatletter 
\AtBeginDocument{\bidi@isloaded{arabxetex}}
\makeatother
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%---------------------------------------------
\usepackage[novoc]{arabxetex}
%---------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
% bdAyt Alw_tyqT
\rhead{\textarab{Alf.sl Al'awl}}
\lhead{\textarab{`nwAn Alf.sl}}
%---------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{n.zryT}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\textLR{\arabic{theorem}}}
%---------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\chapter{\textarab{alqsmT}}
\begin{arab}
\begin{theorem}
kl `dad yqbl alqsmT `l 1.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
kl `dad yqbl alqsmT `l nfsh.
\end{theorem}
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I try to put \usepackage{arqam} and i put the files arqam.sty in the same document but there is many error why please ?

Comment: i want to obtain the number 1,2,3,...

Comment: and we can't do \chapter ?

Comment: for numbering you need to add `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\textLR{\arabic{theorem}}}`

Comment: for chapter,  you need to use the `book` class, i am sorry, and then `\chapter{\textarab{alqsmT}}` for example.

Comment: thank you but the numbering still the same, how to do ?

Comment: did you try `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\textLR{\arabic{theorem}}}`? In general you need `\textLR{1234567890}`.

Comment: i do exactly what you say in your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71050/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-touhami).